# How to load an image with unique names from a private folder?

Tags: objective-c, image, ipad, uiimageview, filenames

I am working on an app for iPad where I want to have lets say 100 jpg's in a folder.
They could be named like `01.jpg`, `02.jpg` etc.

In my app I like to browse those images and when clicking on one of them I need the name of the image to be able to send some data over the network (the data part works fine).

I tried to use `UIImagePicker` but I found out there are no name connected to the  actual image.

Then I made another approach where I have a number of pages where I have buttons and here I load in the images which works fine as long the are a part of the recourse of the project...

But here comes the real problem.

The user of the app should be able to change those images over time without recompiling the app.

So I do look for a way to have a folder where the user can place/replace images with the names `01.jpg` etc and the app to use those updated images.

Ideas are very welcome.

Wiljan

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand what you mean, but You can save images in your application documents folder. You can find more details at:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW6

You can also use NSFileManager to copy files.

what I suggest to do is :

- put default images on project resources.
- At first start, copy files to documents folder.
- always use images from documents folder.

Comment: It sounds as a good idea ... then ther app will always work in the firt plase then the user can change imeges by pointing to the right ones in the document folder